# JdbcTemplate and stored procedure without params

Tags: spring-boot, jdbc, oracle12c, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I want to call a stored procedure in Spring Boot using JdbcTemplate.

In my Oracle DB:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY P_MENU AS 
..
procedure menusVegans
  is
..
END;
```

from my Java application. I've tried

```
jdbcTemplate.update("call P_MENU.menusVegans");
```

and

```
jdbcTemplate.execute("P_MENU.menusVegans");
```

and

```
jdbcTemplate.execute("call P_MENU.menusVegans");
```

and

```
jdbcTemplate.execute("execute call P_MENU.menusVegans");
```

and

```
SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)

                .withProcedureName("P_MENU.menusVegans");
        simpleJdbcCall.execute(null);
```

all with errors.

Comment: Have you tried `BEGIN P_MENU.menusVegans; END` rather than `call`?

Comment: @MT0, please convert to answer

Comment: If you receive an error, then you should include the full stacktrace in your question. Don't make us guess about the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using

```
call P_MENU.menusVegans
```

You should use an anonymous PL/SQL block:

```
BEGIN P_MENU.menusVegans; END
```